VM Error: Display output is not activated
Столкнулся с такой проблемой: при запуске виртуальной машины вылетает ошибка: Display output is not activated

Ошибка вылетает если в параметрах дисплея выбрать virtio-gpu-pci. Однако, если выбрать virtio-vga - ошибки не возникает. Речь идет именно о графической установке AstraLinux.
На некоторых форумах пишут, что необходимо выбрать virtio-ramfb-gl (GPU Supported), но лично мне это не помогло.
В чем причина такого поведения?

MacBook AirM2 macOS Sequoia 15.0
UTM 4.5.3
Actra Linunx ...

